# How to display image on mouseover above the respective filename - angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am able to display file image and title on mouseovering for respective file. But for all filename the image and title is displaying in same place.

I need to display the respective image and title on above of respective filename. When page gets loaded I saw this small box. I don't know why.

[image: Initially]

After moving mouseover on first filename or second filename it will display the image and title in the same place as below.

[image: image on mouseover]

**HTML :**

```
<style>
 .hover-image {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }

    img.hover-image {
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;

    }

    .hover-title {
        color:black; 
        position: absolute; 
        margin-top: -20px;
    }

</style>

<div class="file-image-tags1">
            <ul>
                <span style="width: 200px;"><a ng-show="hideHoveredImage==false;" class="hover-title">{{hoverTitle}}<img class="hover-image" src="{{hoveredImage}}"></a></span>
                <li ng-repeat="image in files | filter :'image'" >

                    <div class="file-tag-baloon1" ng-mouseover="hoverImg(image.id)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
                        <span>


                            <a ng-click="photoPreview(image.id);" >{{image.fileshortname}}</a>

                        </span>
                        <span><a ng-click="removeImage(image.id)" class="remove1">X</a></span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and share the link?

Comment: Can you try ng-show to ng-if?

Comment: Its working as before. No changes is seen. My value is displaying in constant place.

Comment: I want to display the image and title of the file above filename. when user mouseover on filename. As I am using ng-repeat to display all the files. How to display the image and title above the respective filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the angular built in directives,
Check out the below code

**HTML**

```
<span ng-hide="show">
    <img ng-src="https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random" />

    </span>
  <br/>
  <span ng-mouseover="show=!show" ng-mouseleave="show=!show">
     Image name </span>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.show="false";
});
```

**Update 1**:

Based on the comment I updated as below

**Angular Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.show = "false";
  $scope.arrayofJson = [{
      imageTitle: "someImageName1",
      imagePath: "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
      show: "false"
    }, { 
      imageTitle: "someImageName2",
      imagePath: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random",
      show: "false"
    }, { 
      imageTitle: "someImageName3",
      imagePath: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random",
      show: "false"
    }, {
      imageTitle: "someImageName4",
      imagePath: "https://unsplash.it/200/300/?random",
      show: "false"
    }


  ];
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayofJson">
    <span ng-hide="item.show">
    <img ng-src="{{item.imagePath}}" />    </span>
    <br/>
    <span ng-mouseover="item.show=!item.show" ng-mouseleave="item.show=!item.show">
     {{item.imageTitle}} </span>

  </div>
```

The plunker remains the same and it is updated. Check out the [**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/oH1PCJoDWt9qAffIWSmo)

Comment: I am getting the image but for all files the images are displaying in some fixed same place. But it should display above the respective filename.

Comment: @kalai was this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
.file-image-tags1
{
position : absolute;
}
```

Comment: No changes is noticed. Its displaying as before.

Comment: I want to display the image and title of the file above filename. when user mouseover on filename. As I am using ng-repeat to display all the files. How to display the image and title above the respective filename.

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ng-if ng-show/hide like below example.

```
$scope.hoverIn = function(){
    this.hoverImage = true;
};

$scope.hoverOut = function(){
    this.hoverImage = false;
};

<ul>
<span ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">Hover Me</span>
        <span ng-show="hoverImage">
            <img>.....</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in function you can pass the file name and you can do much more